# How to store JSON data to IEnumerable and loop through it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I want to call multiple API (with different parameters), then store them into some kind of a container. Then I'd like to grab this container, send to my view (Razor), loop through it and append it to my DOM (or display it).

The following didn't work.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string[] day = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"};
    IEnumerable<API> results = new IEnumerable<API>();
    for (var i = 0; i < day.Length; i++)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.example.com/values/d=" + day[i]);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content;

        results[i] = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<API>(responseContent);
    }

    return View(results);
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, because an `IEnumerable` doesn't have an indexer:

```
results[i] =
```

Alternatively you can use a list:

```
List<API> results = new List<API>();
for (var i = 0; i < day.Length; i++) //can also be foreach
{ 
   ///omitted 

   results.Add(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<API>(responseContent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the IEnumerable type in this way:

```
IEnumerable<API> results = new List<API>();


results.Add(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<API>(responseContent));
```

> results   ==> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   {System.Collections.Generic.List}

Comment: You can't use Add() with an IEnumerable type object, IEnumerable is for enumerating over collections. You would need to declare it as a list : List<API> results = new List<API>();

Comment: the declaration of the object is done with IEnumerable<API>, but the instance with List<API>()

Comment: It give me an error: "'IEnumerable<API>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<API>' could be found"

Comment: If you store the collection as an IEnumerable<API> you lose the ability to call methods used in List unless you cast it back to a List; however if you are doing that there isn't much point storing it as an IEnumerable in the first place.

Comment: You have used this code: IEnumerable<API> results = new List<API>();

Comment: @Stefan answer below is correct.

Comment: Yes, but the goal is to return that type of data IEnumerable, it is normal that you will lose all the ability to call methods used in List

Comment: you can use the other solution, but if you want to return IEnumerable

Comment: List<T> implements the IEnumerable<T> interface.

Comment: I used @Stefan answer, then in the Razor, I have "@model IEnumerable<Models.API>" to loop through to the list.